# Indigo and Kinetic Compatibility

Tags: ros, ros-comm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm  (perhaps foolishly) integrating a Kinetic ROS install with a third-party package whose implementation is built on Indigo.

In initial tests with clients built on Kinetic I've been able to read every message published by nodes built on Indigo.

However I am unable to subscribe to and read messages published by nodes built on Kinetic by clients built on Indigo.

Can anyone verify for me, is this a fool's errand? Is ros_comm as built in Indigo sufficiently different that is not fully compatible with Kinetic. There is precious little documentation regarding the compatibility between ROS versions so it is hard to tell without testing.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269919/indigo-and-kinetic-compatibility/) by [vschmidt](https://answers.ros.org/users/25950/vschmidt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 242 on 2017-08-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-30**:
Your question seems similar to your previous one (#q252109), which was also answered and referred to three other answers. Was something not clear then?

**Comment by [vschmidt](https://answers.ros.org/users/25950/vschmidt/) on 2017-08-30**:
Thanks for reminding me that I'd asked the question. Must be frustrating. :) Now I'm actually trying it. I'm defining the message definitions explicitly. However, I am finding a "Unknown Error" in the master.log when the Indigo client attempts to subscribe to the Kinetic publisher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I discovered my problem here. I did not realize that ROS requires fully resolvable host-names in addition to routable ip addresses. When I completely configured all hosts in /etc/hosts (including the local hostname, and by that I don't mean localhost), I was then able to successfully pass data between endpoints without error.

---

Originally posted by [vschmidt](https://answers.ros.org/users/25950/vschmidt/) with karma: 242 on 2017-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0